# Can I lean on that ajax callbacks will be executed in the order they are defined?

Tags: jquery, ajax

If I have 2 ajax() functions inside of document.ready:

```
$(function() {
  ...  
  $.ajax({ // 1st
    success: function (result) {
    ...
    });
  });
  ...
  $.ajax({ // 2nd
    success: function (result) {
    ...
    });
  });
  ...
});
```

and the 2nd's success results depends on 1st's success results, in that case the code is ok? Or should I put the 2nd ajax into the callback of the 1st?

Comment: since it is an asynchronous call, you should put the second one inside the `success` of the first one.

Comment: sorry, but asynchronous means that the execution will go further and at some time the callbacks will be executed... I would like to know about the order of callbacks...

Comment: `2nd's success results depends on 1st's success results` means what then?

Comment: I set a global variable in the 1st which is then used in the 2nd

Comment: @user3719454 - no, you cannot "lean on ...".

Comment: @Igor: thanks for the answer... so the 1st callback can be overtaken by the 2nd, sure? If you were to put your answer with some reference, I would accept it

Comment: It all depends on how long it takes it to return a response, there's no way to know what asynchronous call will complete first, but there are ways to get the response data in a certain order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot expect that the order of receiving responses to asynchronous ajax calls is the same as the order in which the ajax requests are sent.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

"... meaning that the operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion is not guaranteed. ..."

Comment: so if I send 1st request and then the 2nd request, then it is possible that the server will return the 2nd respose and after it the 1st. And in that case the 2nd callback will be executed first and after it the 1st callback?

Answer (score 1):

Those are asynchronous calls, which means that event if the two calls are sent in the specified order, the answer can come from the server in any order. Thus, it is possible according to Murphy's law that the second callback would be called before the first. In that case, the variable you expected to be set would not be.

This explains why "erkaner" told you to put the second Ajax call in the success of the first one. This will garantee that the execution will take place in the expected order.

Answer (score 0):

If the second one has to be executed ONLY if the first one is a success, yes you put it in the success of the first one